# Set minimum order value only if no coupon applied

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using a snippet to set minimum order value on WooCommerce store. However, I am having some issues if coupon is applied.

For example, minimum order value is 500 and customer applies a coupon with a value of 500 - This would give a subtotal of 0 and therefore the system won't allow the customer to buy because the subtotal is less than minimum order value.

I am therefore trying to rewrite the minimum order value snippet so it won't set a minimum if a coupon is applied.

After doing some research I found that I should check if coupon is applied by using `!empty($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons)`. However, this doesn't seem to work. What am I missing ??

```
// MINIMUM ORDER AMOUNT

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 50;

    if ( (WC()->cart->total <= $minimum) && !empty($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons) ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order ' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the order total amount is **less than or equal to** minimum amount, if it returns true means order total is 500 or less than 500, then you can show the error message.

> ```
> if ( (WC()->cart->total <= $minimum) && !empty($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons) ) {
>    // PRINT ERROR MESSAGE
> } else {
>    // DO YOUR CODE
> }
> ```

Hope it works!

Comment: It sounds like the right way to go! However, I've tried updating the if statement but no luck. I have updated code in question just to make sure that was how you meant it should be written :)

Comment: Yes I meant it but if it isn't working, I think we need to get coupon code's amount and compare it to the minimum value we have set, to get the solution. Sounds right to you?

Comment: Like, if ((WC()->cart->total <= $minimum) && ( ( !empty($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons) ) && ( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons->value <= $minimum) ){ // PRINT ERROR }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like this?

```php
// MINIMUM ORDER AMOUNT

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set variables
    $minimum = 500;
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( (WC()->cart->total <= $minimum) && isset($woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons) ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'NB! Vi sender ikke bestillinger ud under %s, din nuværende total er %s.' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'NB! Vi sender ikke bestillinger ud under %s, din nuværende total er %s.' , 
                    wc_price( $minimum ), 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mads! Unfortunately it didn't make any difference...

Comment: what about now?